# HTML: How do I make the oninvalid alert appear only once when more than one required fields is invalid

Tags: html

Consider the following code:

```
<input type="text" oninvalid="alert('Missing required fields!');" id="input1" name="input1" required/>
<input type="text" oninvalid="alert('Missing required fields!');" id="input2" name="input2" required/>
<input type="text" oninvalid="alert('Missing required fields!');" id="input3" name="input3" required/>
```

I wish that regardless of how many of the three fields the user leaves blank, the alert message only appears once. With my current code, the alert message is displayed as many times as there are invalid fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JavaScript function that is called by `oninvalid`. It works by using an if statement that is only true the first time the function is called, after that alert() will no longer be called.

```
var once = false;
function prompt(){
   if(once == false){
      alert('Missing required fields!');
      once = true;
   }
}
```

Then use `oninvalid="prompt();"` in your input tag.